# JSON_DECODE for each php not working

Tags: php, json

This is my sample.txt

> {
>       "Messages": [
>           {
>               "address": "AIS",
>               "body": "3989เพื่อป้องกันมิจฉาชีพอย่าบอกรหัสผู้ใด AIS จะไม่ถามรหัสจากคุณ",
>               "date": "1436164374077",
>               "read": "0",
>               "msgtype": "inbox"
>           },
>           {
>               "address": "+66819129634",
>               "body": "7778",
>               "date": "1436090922311",
>               "read": "0",
>               "msgtype": "inbox"
>           },
>           {
>               "address": "+66819129634",
>               "body": "7778",
>               "date": "1436090922132",
>               "read": "1",
>               "msgtype": "sent"
>           }
>   ]
>   }

```
<?php
$jsondata = file_get_contents("sample.txt");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($json['Messages'] as $message) : ?>
<li><?php echo $message['address']; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message['body']; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message['data']; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message['read']; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message['msgtype']; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I don't  know  why is not  working

i think it issue about my foreach

Comment: Not working means what?

Comment: how is json data stored in sample.txt ? may be coz of special characters.

Comment: Dump the $json make sure its an array,or make sure the you actually get json data

Comment: There is no issue with your for each loop.
I checked it with execution and it is working good.
I just tried by putting the file content as a string of $jsondata.

Comment: See here.  http://codepad.org/0psLIHrp

Comment: my data is validate on json [http://jsonlint.com/]

Comment: Maybe edit your question with the whole code,is your extension php,do you have apache running?

Comment: I think issue might be with your file_get_contents()  function.

Comment: @raj  Why is still not working .

Comment: You probably haven't set the proper charset.

Comment: your code is working properly here is output : https://ideone.com/mPGRyw it seems that file_get_content() function is blocked by server for security purpose you can use curl for getting content of file.

Comment: Can you debug it by echoing $jsondata and $json once.
So that u can get some issue idea.

Comment: it problem about  file_get_content ();   I think i try  not use that 
it work .

Comment: @kevin  you know how to unblocked or fixed about my server security

Answer (score 2):

Fix $message['data'] to $message['date']. I think the issue is with array index.

And i assume that it is being converted in Stdclass Object.

If you are not able to see errors then you may use.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

You can try this.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($json->Messages as $message) : ?>
<li><?php echo $message->address; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message->body; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message->data; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message->read; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message->msgtype; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah that point i mistake but it still not work , Thank for you help

Answer (score 0):

use the following so that it will give the results

```
<?php foreach($json['Messages'] as $message) : ?>
<ul>
<li><?php echo $message['address']; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message['body']; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message['date']; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message['read']; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $message['msgtype']; ?></li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and the result will be

```
AIS
3989à¹€à,žà¸·à¹ˆà¸­à¸›à¹‰à¸­à¸‡à¸à¸±à¸™à¸¡à¸´à¸ˆà¸‰à¸²à¸Šà¸µà¸žà¸­à¸¢à¹ˆà¸²à¸šà¸­à¸à¸£à¸«à¸±à¸ªà¸œà¸¹à¹‰à¹ƒà¸” AIS à¸ˆà¸°à¹„à¸¡à¹ˆà¸–à¸²à¸¡à¸£à¸«à¸±à¸ªà¸ˆà¸²à¸à¸„à¸¸à¸“
1436164374077
0
inbox

+66819129634
7778
1436090922311
0
inbox

+66819129634
7778
1436090922132
1
sent
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents($path);
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);

        foreach($json['Messages'] as $message){
             echo $message['address'];
             echo $message['body'];
             echo $message['date'];
             echo $message['read'];
             echo $message['msgtype'];
        }
```

There was a problem with the array-index:

```
echo $message['data'];
```

'data' is not an array key, it is 'date'

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use curl because file get content is  not secure below is code that may help you

```html
function get_content($URL){
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          return $data;
      }


 echo get_content('http://example.com');
```